# SignalR Clients.Caller(Clients.Caller.GroupName) does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am going through tutorials on SignalR and cannot figure out why this does not work.

This works:

```
Clients.Group("TestGroup").displayText(person.Name, person.Message);
```

This does not work:

```
Clients.Group(Clients.Caller.GroupName).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);
```

The javascript code:

```
var broadcaster = $.connection.groupHub;
broadcaster.client.displayText = function (name, message) {
    $('#messages').append('<li>' + name + ' said:' + message + '</li>');
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('#broadcast').off().on("click", function () {

        var group = "GroupTest";       
        broadcaster.server.join(group);
        broadcaster.state.GroupName = group;
        broadcaster.server.broadcastMessage({ Name: $('#name').val(), Message: $('#message').val() });
        broadcaster.server.leave(group);
    });
```

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me and its probably something small I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by casting to string:

```
Clients.Group(Clients.Caller.GroupName).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);
```

should be:

```
Clients.Group((string)Clients.Caller.GroupName).displayText(person.Name, person.Message);
```

I assume this is because the Clients.Caller and broadcast.state are dynamic.
The book I am reading does not mention this however, either due to an error, or a difference perhaps in versions of SignalR